# Copy depth texture to RGBA texture

Tags: opengl

I have created a texture using

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_NV, 0, CONSENSUS_DEPTH_COMPONENT, width, height, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, 0);
```

This texture is used in other code and filled with depth. Now I want to copy the depth values to an RGBA texture (doesn't matter which color channel).

How can I do this?

Comment: Why do you need to do that? You can read from the depth texture in a shader or using glReadPixels.

Comment: I want to use this values in CUDA, so I am limited in the texture formats I can use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it needs to be fast, I'd say render an orthograhic quad the size of the texture and use a shader to read from the depth texture and write to the target texture.

If performance doesn't matter that much you can use PBOs (might even be faster depending on your render pipeline but stalls the CPU). [Here's an overview on said PBOs](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_pbo.html)

I don't know of any inherent OpenGL method to do this.

Comment: I would suggest an additional color attachment instead of new rendering stage.